# How To Do Ajax For Country State City Dropdown In Wordpress Custom Plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Hello Can anyone explain me how to get state list based on particular country selection in wordpress custom plugin, for example: India>Gujarat/Maharashtra etc. Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: can you elaborate more you issue ?

Comment: I need ajax functionality for country>state>city dropdowns in wordpress custom plugin